# change date to datetime datatype in sql server for all table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have date field in many tables in database, now I want to alter date data type to date time data type for all tables, I have searched since many times but I have not found any better solution for that, how can I solve this, do you have any idea or can you write any specific query for me. Thanks.

Comment: Is this MS SQL Server?  What version?

Comment: The only way I have found to do it is to insert the current tables data into a second table, drop the first, and recreate the first table with the appropriate column data types. Then insert the data from table b to table a and drop table b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query:

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Result = @Result + 'Alter Table [' +t.name + '] Alter Column [' + c.name +'] DateTime ' + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable=1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE 'Not NULL' END +' '
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE ty.name = 'Date'
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(t.object_id,'IsUserTable')=1

EXEC(@Result)
```

Comment: thanks @mehdi lotfi this query is syntactically error, please retrieve this.

Comment: @Shohel. I test my query before say as answare, and didn't have any problem. can you say error of this query.

Comment: Thanks @mehdi lotfi, sorry brother it is working but spelling mistake.

Comment: Hi,@mehdi lotfi, please change "Aulter Table" to "Alter Table" and remove GO

Comment: need space before ' Alter Table'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58048/discussion-between-mehdi-lotfi-and-shohel).